# Ubuntu keyutils error

Tags: 14.04

How to resolve this error ?

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# gcc a.c -o a -lkeyutils -Wall
a.c:8:22: fatal error: keyutils.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
root@ubuntu:/tmp#
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy keyutils`

Comment: root@ubuntu:/tmp# apt-cache policy keyutils
keyutils:
  Installed: 1.5.6-1
  Candidate: 1.5.6-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@ubuntu:/tmp#

Comment: I'm sorry - I think I meant to type `apt-cache policy libkeyutils-dev`

Comment: root@ubuntu:/tmp# apt-cache policy libkeyutils-dev
libkeyutils-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.6-1
  Version table:
     1.5.6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
root@ubuntu:/tmp#

Comment: K - that is the package that is supposed to contain libkeys.h - please do `sudo apt-get install libkeyutils-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this error check the installation status of *libkeyutils-dev*

`apt-cache policy libkeyutils-dev`

If the package has not been installed, install it with

`sudo apt-get install libkeyutils-dev`